# Spring Form Handling Form Exeption

Tags: java, model-view-controller, spring-mvc

When i go to form site `Spring` thorow exeptions:

```
01:34:09,257 ERROR [org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'name' available as request attribute: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'name' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:174) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:194) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.autogenerateFor(LabelTag.java:129) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.resolveFor(LabelTag.java:119) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.writeTagContent(LabelTag.java:89) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.person_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005flabel_005f0(person_jsp.java:112)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.person_jsp._jspService(person_jsp.java:67)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:840) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:622) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:560) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]

01:34:09,275 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/SpringMVCreName].[jsp]] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'name' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:174) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:194) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.autogenerateFor(LabelTag.java:129) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.resolveFor(LabelTag.java:119) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.writeTagContent(LabelTag.java:89) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.person_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005flabel_005f0(person_jsp.java:112)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.person_jsp._jspService(person_jsp.java:67)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:840) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:622) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:560) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]

01:34:09,292 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/SpringMVCreName].[mvc-dispatcher]] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet mvc-dispatcher threw exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'name' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:174) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:194) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.autogenerateFor(LabelTag.java:129) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.resolveFor(LabelTag.java:119) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.writeTagContent(LabelTag.java:89) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.person_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005flabel_005f0(person_jsp.java:112)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.person_jsp._jspService(person_jsp.java:67)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:840) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:622) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:560) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
```

I have form `person.jsp`:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Person form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="addPerson.html">

        <form:label path="name"></form:label>

        <form:label path="lastName"></form:label>

        <form:label path="age"></form:label>

        <input type="submit" value="Add Contact" />

    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

And controler:

```
@Controller
public class FormControler {

    @RequestMapping(value="/addPerson", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    private void contrler(@ModelAttribute("person")Person person, BindingResult result) {

        System.out.println("Name "+person.getName());

    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/person", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView showContscts() {

        return new ModelAndView("person", "command", new Person());
    }

}
```

And `Person.java`:

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private String lastName;
    private String age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }


}
```

Also `index` site wih `<a href`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<html>
<body>

    <a href="person">Person</a>

</body>
</
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem using advice in this topic, but i also i change name in `ModelAndView("person", "command", new Person())` from `command` to `person`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind your form to the model, this way:

```
<form:form method="POST" action="addPerson.html" modelAttribute="person">
    <form:label path="name"></form:label>
    <form:label path="lastName"></form:label>
    <form:label path="age"></form:label>
    <input type="submit" value="Add Contact" />
</form: form>
```

Comment: I edit form but I still see this same exeption.

Comment: just to confirm you did use `form:form` tag and not `form` directly right?

Comment: Yes, I change to `form:form` and add `modelAttribute`.

Answer (score 1):

You have you form in jsp file : suppose jsp name is person.jsp

```
<form:form method="POST" action="addPerson" modelAttribute="person">
    <form:label path="name"></form:label>
    <form:label path="lastName"></form:label>
    <form:label path="age"></form:label>
    <input type="submit" value="Add Contact" />
</form: form>
```

Now the action method from where your person.jsp is loaded should be something like this :

```
@Controller
public class FormControler {

    @RequestMapping(value="/addPerson", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    private void contrler(@ModelAttribute("person")Person person, BindingResult result)  { 
        System.out.println("Name "+person.getName());
    }

    // Your this method is going to show pseron jsp page
    // dont return model and view, instead try this

    @RequestMapping(value="/person", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showContacts(Model model) {
        // your jsp demands Person.java as modelAttribute
        // add that POJO in model and send along with your jsp

        model.addAttribute("person", new Pseron()); // this attribute name should be same as it is in modelAttribute of jsp form
        return "person";
    }
}
```

Give this a try.

Comment: Thanks, I solve my problem before this post. But this information is usefull.